# PHP Merging files not working

Tags: php

Merging files isn't working anymore and I'm not sure why. I'm not getting any on-screen errors so I checked my error log and this is what I see:

```
[Tue Mar 18 09:06:08 2014] [error] [client 10.0.50.12] PHP   1. {main}() /home/toolplas/public_html/main/phplib/edit_workorder.php:0, referer: https://new.tps.com/edit_workorder.php?job_num=1000&id=4173
[Tue Mar 18 09:06:08 2014] [error] [client 10.0.50.12] PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/toolplas/public_html/main/phplib/edit_workorder.php on line 50, referer: https://new.tps.com/edit_workorder.php?job_num=1000&id=4173
[Tue Mar 18 09:06:08 2014] [error] [client 10.0.50.12] PHP Stack trace:, referer: https://new.tps.com/edit_workorder.php?job_num=1000&id=4173
[Tue Mar 18 09:06:08 2014] [error] [client 10.0.50.12] PHP   1. {main}() /home/toolplas/public_html/main/phplib/edit_workorder.php:0, referer: https://new.tps.com/edit_workorder.php?job_num=1000&id=4173
[Tue Mar 18 09:06:08 2014] [error] [client 10.0.50.12] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: affect in /home/toolplas/public_html/main/phplib/edit_workorder.php on line 80, referer: https://new.tps.com/edit_workorder.php?job_num=1000&id=4173
[Tue Mar 18 09:06:08 2014] [error] [client 10.0.50.12] PHP Stack trace:, referer: https://new.tps.com/edit_workorder.php?job_num=1000&id=4173
[Tue Mar 18 09:06:08 2014] [error] [client 10.0.50.12] PHP   1. {main}() /home/toolplas/public_html/main/phplib/edit_workorder.php:0, referer: https://new.tps.com/edit_workorder.php?job_num=1000&id=4173
[Tue Mar 18 09:06:08 2014] [error] [client 10.0.50.12] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: file in /home/toolplas/public_html/main/phplib/edit_workorder.php on line 282, referer: https://new.tps.com/edit_workorder.php?job_num=1000&id=4173
[Tue Mar 18 09:06:08 2014] [error] [client 10.0.50.12] PHP Stack trace:, referer: https://new.tps.com/edit_workorder.php?job_num=1000&id=4173
[Tue Mar 18 09:06:08 2014] [error] [client 10.0.50.12] PHP   1. {main}() /home/toolplas/public_html/main/phplib/edit_workorder.php:0, referer: https://new.tps.com/edit_workorder.php?job_num=1000&id=4173
[Tue Mar 18 09:06:08 2014] [error] [client 10.0.50.12] PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/toolplas/public_html/main/phplib/edit_workorder.php on line 282, referer: https://new.tps.com/edit_workorder.php?job_num=1000&id=4173
[Tue Mar 18 09:06:08 2014] [error] [client 10.0.50.12] PHP Stack trace:, referer: https://new.tps.com/edit_workorder.php?job_num=1000&id=4173
[Tue Mar 18 09:06:08 2014] [error] [client 10.0.50.12] PHP   1. {main}() /home/toolplas/public_html/main/phplib/edit_workorder.php:0, referer: https://new.tps.com/edit_workorder.php?job_num=1000&id=4173
[Tue Mar 18 09:06:08 2014] [error] [client 10.0.50.12] PHP Warning:  mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /home/toolplas/public_html/main/edit_workorder.php on line 176, referer: https://new.tps.com/edit_workorder.php?job_num=1000&id=4173
[Tue Mar 18 09:06:08 2014] [error] [client 10.0.50.12] PHP Stack trace:, referer: https://new.tps.com/edit_workorder.php?job_num=1000&id=4173
[Tue Mar 18 09:06:08 2014] [error] [client 10.0.50.12] PHP   1. {main}() /home/toolplas/public_html/main/edit_workorder.php:0, referer: https://new.tps.com/edit_workorder.php?job_num=1000&id=4173
```

Its not specific to one Work Order as its happening to all of them and I'm not sure why its no longer working.

Here's the code:

```
if(isset($wo['files_to_merge'])){
    //$prev_files = $_POST['file'];
    //$files = $_FILES['file'];
    $folder = "/home/toolplas/public_html/main/pdf/temp/WO$wo_id/";
    if(!file_exists($folder)){
        mkdir($folder);
    }
    $files = array();
    if(isset($_POST['file'])){
        foreach($_POST['file'] as $key => $item){
            $files[] = array('order' => $key, 'filename' => $item);
        }
    }
    /*foreach($_FILES['file']['name'] as $key => $item){
        $name = date('U') . preg_replace('/[^\w\._]+/', '', basename($item));
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$key], $folder . $name)){
            $files[] = array('order' => $key, 'filename' => $name);
        } else {
            debug('File Not Uploaded ' . $name);
        }
    }*/
    foreach($_FILES['file']['error'] as $key => $error){
        $tmp_name= $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$key];
        $name = date('U') . preg_replace('/[^\w\._]+/', '', basename($_FILES['file']['name'][$key]));
        if($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK){
            move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $folder . $name);
            $files[] = array('order' => $key, 'filename' => $name);
        } else {
            debug("Cannot Move File: $tmp_name -> $name");
            debug("File Error: $error");
        }
    }
    $sql = "DELETE FROM workorder_files WHERE workorder_id = $wo_id;";
    echo $sql;
    mysqli_query($dbc3, $sql) or die("Query 11: " . mysqli_error($dbc3));
    foreach($files as $file){
        $sql = "INSERT INTO workorder_files(workorder_id, filename, `order`) VALUES($wo_id, '" . $file['filename'] . "', " . $file['order'] . ");";
        mysqli_query($dbc3, $sql) or die("Query 12: " . mysqli_error($dbc3));
    }
    //print_r($_FILES);
}
```

Employees told me it was working fine Friday and over the weekend.

This is what the form looks like,

[image: Form]

HTML:

```
       <tr>
         <th>Files To Merge?</th>
           <td><input type="checkbox" class='files_to_merge' id="files_to_merge" name='workorder[files_to_merge]' {% if files is not empty %}checked='checked'{% endif %} />{{ functions.alert('More to the right') }}</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <th>Posted By</th>
          <td>{{ user.name }}<input readonly="readonly" type="hidden" name="workorder[user]" value="{{ user.id }}" /></td>
       </tr>
```

Comment: where does `$wo['files_to_merge']` come from?
what is on line 282 in your `edit_workorder.php` file?
this is very little information for the quite complex problem.
basically, all the help i could give you is "learn the priciples of debugging php code".

Comment: @AndreschSerj Edited the post so you can see where it comes from. Line 282 is above: foreach($_FILES['file']['error'] as $key => $error){

Comment: Well line 50 would be interesting as well since your erro shows that the foreach in line 50 has an invalid input as well.

Comment: @AndreschSerj I don't think line 50 has anything to do with it. There is an option to keep "tfiles" and I've noticed if its unchecked it throws that error, if its checked it doesn't. Here's line 50 anyway: http://codepad.org/h1jtNNfT

Comment: Well, your error log states: `PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/toolplas/public_html/main/phplib/edit_workorder.php on line 50` and if you want to debug the error, line 50 is of importance. However, if you fixed your problem, consider deleting this question since it won't be of any help for anyone in the future.

Comment: @AndreschSerj By your logic, any posted question that doesn't result in a solution is a useless question. I asked it so a solution can be found. I fail to believe that a question won't be of any help to anyone in the future because if and when I do figure this out, my solution could point someone in the right direction and help them solve their problem. 

Now, I looked at line 50, and my impression is that there is nothing there that would stop files from merging considering it was working before. Not sure if you saw the link I posted, codepad.org/h1jtNNfT 

Thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: you do not work with a commonly used software (at least you didn't say if it is so) and you write that the solutions was *an option to keep "tfiles"* which is not a php option or anything anyone else, not working wqith your system would have right? So why would this be of any help? Your error log shows a problem in line 50, yet you do not agree that it might be usefull to look into that, so your "Solution" does not seem to follow any debugging concepts.

Comment: @AndreschSerj Thats because tfiles are just that, files. They're just .igs files, they don't have anything to do with merging pdfs or images. I said that before. I didn't say the solution was that ? I also said that the error occurs because I didn't check off "Keep current tfiles" or select a tfile. As for a solution, I feel like it might be a permissions issue with the output folder.